# Oracle regex match whitespace

Tags: regex, oracle, whitespace

I'm trying to change a value in oracle with regex:

```
input: <input id="f_alta">13/10/2016  10:10:10</input>
output: 13/10/2016  10:10:10
```

well, to get inside the node I use: **([\s0-9/:]+)** but is no working, anyway I use: **([ 0-9/:]+)** and works, why is not working with the first one?

I'm using oracle sql developer for tests.

Example:

NOT WORKING:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('<input id="f_alta">13/10/2016  10:10:10</input>', '<input id="f_alta">([\s0-9/:]+)</input>', '\1' ) from dual
```

WORKING:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('<input id="f_alta">13/10/2016  10:10:10</input>', '<input id="f_alta">([ 0-9/:]+)</input>', '\1' ) from dual
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the `\s` is a Perl-like construct and Oracle regex is POSIX based, it is safer to use the POSIX character class `[:space:]` (to include vertical whitespace) or `[:blank:]` (to only match spaces and tabs).

E.g. use

```
([[:space:]0-9/:]+)
```

Remember to always use POSIX character classes inside bracket expressions (so, to match one alpha character, use `[[:alpha:]]`, i.e. the name of the class must be inside colons and double square brackets).